# Add a child to a Dynamic Supervisor in Elixir

Tags: elixir, erlang-otp, erlang-supervisor

I am trying to create a `DynamicSupervisor` to supervise another `GenServer` on request to it and then trying to test it.

**Here is my code for `NodeDynamicSupervisor`:**

```ex
defmodule NodeDynamicSupervisor do
  use DynamicSupervisor

  def start_link() do
    DynamicSupervisor.start_link(__MODULE__, :ok, name: __MODULE__)
  end

  def init(:ok) do
    DynamicSupervisor.init(strategy: :one_for_one)
  end

  def add_node(private_key, public_key, address, num_of_coins) do
    child_spec = {Node, {private_key, public_key, address, num_of_coins}}
    DynamicSupervisor.start_child(__MODULE__, child_spec)
  end
end
```

---

**Here's how I'm testing it:**

```ex
defmodule NodeCreationTest do
  use ExUnit.Case
  import ExUnit.CaptureIO

  test "should create node" do
    {:ok, node_pid} = NodeDynamicSupervisor.start_link()
    capture_io(node_pid.add_node(private_key, public_key, address, 0))
  end 
end
```

**And this is the error I get:**

```ex
 code: capture_io(node_pid.add_node(private_key, public_key, address, 0))
 stacktrace:
   :erlang.apply(#PID<0.163.0>, :add_node, [])
   test/create_nodes_test.exs:12: (test)
```

Why am I not able to add a node and getting this error instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two issues with your code:

---

**1. You can't call methods on a `pid`:**

You're calling `node_pid.add_node(...)` in your test which is incorrect, when you should be calling the function from the module. Since your `DynamicSupervisor` process is named (`name: __MODULE__`) and your `add_node/4` is already passing the process pid/name in the implementation, you can just call it directly:

```ex
NodeDynamicSupervisor.add_node(private_key, public_key, address, 0)
```

---

**2. [`capture_io`](https://hexdocs.pm/ex_unit/ExUnit.CaptureIO.html#capture_io/1) takes a function as the argument:**

In your case you're first calling the function and passing its result to the method. You need to call the method inside an anonymous function and pass that to `capture_io/1` instead:

```ex
capture_io(fn ->
  NodeDynamicSupervisor.add_node(private_key, public_key, address, 0)
end)
```

Comment: Thank you :) On a side note, don't name your node module `Node`, since you'll be overriding Elixir's built-in module.